# Animate SCNBox height by keeping base in the same y

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a SCNBox object added to a SCNScene through a SCNNode...

```
let box:SCNBox = SCNBox(width: 4, height: 4, length: 4, chamferRadius: 0.1)
box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
let boxNode:SCNNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

My question is how can I animate the height (lets say to 40) and at the same time have the box not grow downward too?

I think I need to change the pivot point to go at the bottom of box?

I am not sure how to do this if that is a solution.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that the [`pivot`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/pivot) is what you need to change. The pivot is a transform — meaning it can encompass scaling and rotation for setting the "base" orientation of a node — but all you need is a translation. To anchor the box at the bottom, translate the pivot by half the box's height:

```
boxNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -(box.height/2), 0)
```

However, this isn't enough to keep it anchored if you change the height — the pivot will stay at half the *old* height, so your box will still grow in both directions. So you'll need to change the pivot as well as the height when animating:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(5)
box.height = 20
boxNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -(box.height/2), 0) // new height
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Since you're animating both `box.height` and `boxNode.pivot` together, it'll stay anchored at the bottom through the animation.